# Reapply Bad Omen if a player drinks milk until player triggers a raid?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't seem to figure out how to test if the player has started a raid with commands.

I'm trying to make it so the bad omen status effect is not removed by milk as any other potion effect would be. So I am able to test for the effect:

```
scoreboard objectives add BadOmen dummy

execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s BadOmen 1
```

Through scoreboards I plan to reapply it using:

```
execute at @a[scores={BadOmen=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen 999999 1
```

But there are two issues. First, I realized I don't know how to end it. I would like to end it only when a raid is triggered, but if I just reapply it whenever the player no longer has it, that would persist even after the player triggers a raid. Also I would like to reapply the same level of bad omen (which I assume uses the "lvl:0" tag). I would also like to do this with Hero of the Village but I assume I can reuse the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Caveats

- With the following methods, Death and Totem of Undying are both ways to get ride of both effects

---

#### Avoiding clearing Bad Omen

First, We create a scoreboard to track when a player drinks milk and track who has the effect:

```
/scoreboard objectives add milk minecraft.used:minecraft.milk_bucket
/scoreboard objectives add bad_omen dummy
```

To prevent a player from using milk to remove the effect, we will do 3 steps:

- Mark who has the effect, setting their `bad_omen` score to the level of the effect. We will need one block of command for each level, you can only get up to level V (5) in vanilla.
- Apply the effect in anyone who has at least score 1 of `bad_omen`
- Reset `milk` and `bad_omen` (In case the bad omen effect ran out naturally, either because of time or raid)

So we translate those to:

Step 1:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b,Amplifier:0b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s bad_omen 1
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b,Amplifier:1b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s bad_omen 2
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b,Amplifier:2b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s bad_omen 3
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b,Amplifier:3b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s bad_omen 4
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b,Amplifier:4b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s bad_omen 5
```

Step 2:

```
/execute as @a[scores={bad_omen=1,milk=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen 999999 0
/execute as @a[scores={bad_omen=2,milk=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen 999999 1
/execute as @a[scores={bad_omen=3,milk=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen 999999 2
/execute as @a[scores={bad_omen=4,milk=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen 999999 3
/execute as @a[scores={bad_omen=5,milk=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:bad_omen 999999 4
```

Step 3:

```
/scoreboard players set @a milk 0
/execute as @a unless entity @s[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:31b}]}] run scoreboard players set @s bad_omen 0
```

Also, responding to your extra question, the way to dettect lvl is actually using `Amplifier:<N>b` where N is the level of the effect starting from 0.

---

#### Avoiding clearing Hero of the Village

We will need:

```
/scoreboard objectives add HeroTime dummy
/scoreboard objectives add HeroLevel dummy
```

For that we do:

- Decrease one from the player HeroTime
- Check if he has HeroTime 0 and potion effect. If so, store his lvl and set his time to 24 minutes
- If he has HeroTime bigger than 0, reapply effect
- If his HeroTime is exactly 1, we clear the effect. This command needs to be at the end. As soon as the next cycle begins, the person with HeroTime of 1 will have 0 (Because of Step 1)

Translation:

Step 1:

```
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1..}] run scoreboard players remove @s HeroTime 1
```

Step 2.1:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:32b,Amplifier:0b}]}] unless score @s HeroTime matches 1.. run scoreboard players set @s HeroLevel 0
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:32b,Amplifier:0b}]}] unless score @s HeroTime matches 1.. run scoreboard players set @s HeroLevel 1
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:32b,Amplifier:0b}]}] unless score @s HeroTime matches 1.. run scoreboard players set @s HeroLevel 2
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:32b,Amplifier:0b}]}] unless score @s HeroTime matches 1.. run scoreboard players set @s HeroLevel 3
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:32b,Amplifier:0b}]}] unless score @s HeroTime matches 1.. run scoreboard players set @s HeroLevel 4
```

Step 2.2:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:32b}]}] unless score @s HeroTime matches 1.. run scoreboard players set @s HeroTime 28800
```

Step 3:

```
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1..,HeroLevel=0}] run effect give @s minecraft:hero_of_the_village 9999 0
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1..,HeroLevel=1}] run effect give @s minecraft:hero_of_the_village 9999 1
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1..,HeroLevel=2}] run effect give @s minecraft:hero_of_the_village 9999 2
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1..,HeroLevel=3}] run effect give @s minecraft:hero_of_the_village 9999 3
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1..,HeroLevel=4}] run effect give @s minecraft:hero_of_the_village 9999 4
```

And step 4:

```
/execute as @a[scores={HeroTime=1}] run effect clear @s minecraft:hero_of_the_village
```

Comment: So I'm not able to try this yet; I will later today and it looks like it will work, but as for hero of the village, I dont want it to be removed by milk, but I see what you mean; that if the player drinks milk to clear it right at the end it would reset and be infinite? So how would I do this? if it takes all those lines like you said, then yes I would appreciate those if you can provide them.

Comment: Wait, perhaps I can use scoreboards to count a variable and reapply the effect until it counts high enough then removes it, independent and not relying on the effect. This means the remaining duration shown would not be accurate, but it would probably be easier than what you were thinking.

Comment: It really is a good idea, the problem is getting the potion time. You'd use the  @a[nbt={...}]` to check if they have the effect, but to get the time into the score is a pain. You see, the `ActiveEffects` is a list of objects (`[{},{},...]`) that contain the id and time inside. There isn't quite a way to ask the game to choose the right object. You need to iterate trough them, which isn't an option on in minecraft. You can copy the nbt tag into another entity and check from there, but that is pretty hacky

Comment: I will have a better look at this. Anyone who is reading the comments and knows a good way to solve this problem, please do.

Comment: Oh I mean have a scoreboard counting until it get to like 24000 or something, and until then the duration shows as xx:xx

Comment: You are absolutly correct, it was easier than I tought. Thank you for the idea. Answer editted, tested and aproved.

Comment: Also, in your original solution, it only resets it if they drink milk, but it could run out naturally.